# Can cluster analysis cluster variables that both positively and negatively correlate with each other?

Tags: clustering, factor-analysis

I received this question by email from a Neuroscience PhD student.

> I would greatly appreciate if you
>   could please let me know whether
>   Factor Analysis could load positively
>   and inversely correlated variables
>   onto the same latent factor, whereas
>   Cluster Analysis can only cluster into
>   the same factor either positively or
>   inversely correlated variables (e.g.,
>   they would be segregated into 2
>   factors).

Comment: "Cluster Analysis" means?

Comment: The answer to the first question is "certainly."  Consider the geometric interpretation of PCA and apply that to (say) a pair of strongly negatively correlated variables.  The principal component must have a positive loading from one and a negative loading from the other.

Comment: Cluster analysis doesn't generate factors.  It finds groups of cases that have multiple characteristics in common.  The words "Cluster Analysis can only cluster into the same factor" don't make sense to me.

Comment: Based on your (@whuber and @rolando2's) comments it sounds like the person who sent me an email may be speaking about statistics in a psychological, possibly SPSS-centric, way. @whuber "Cluster analysis": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis; @rolando2 It is possible to cluster variables e.g., with SPSS hiearchical cluster analysis by variables.

Comment: @Jeromy - that's a useful reminder to make, but still, clustering variables wouldn't result in a "factor" in the usual sense, i.e., there'd be no analog to factor loadings for the different variables (although there would be factor scores).  Is that right?

Comment: @Jeromy The point, amply illustrated by your reference to Wikipedia, is that "cluster analysis" means a huge number of different things.  Without specifying which kind of cluster analysis your student has in mind, the question is vague.

Comment: @rolando2 and @whuber good points.

Comment: @rolando2 @whuber As @Jeromy said, we can apply (hierarchical) cluster analysis (CA) onto the variables, as we would do for highlighting homogeneous groups of individuals, based on a certain metric. Another way of constructing scales is to apply *item clustering*, as proposed by William Revelle (Multivariate Behavioral Research 1979 14:57-74), based on [Cronbach's alpha](http://bit.ly/mKsFdi). Like for multidimensional scaling, the object of interest (variables or individuals) is choosen by the researcher. Now, I must admit that the question looks vague because nothing is said about CA...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### General interpration of question:

The question is a bit confusing, but I interpret it as follows.

- **Factor Analysis**: When a survey has multiple items and some are positively worded (e.g., "I am the life of the party") and others are negatively worded (e.g., "I avoid social interaction"), factor analysis often assigns such items to the same factor.
  For example, extraversion items load positively on one factor and introversion items load negatively on the same factor.
- **Cluster Analysis**: It is possible to cluster by variables.

  - In **R** you can use `dist` to generate a distance matrix and then send it to `hclust` to perform a hierarchical cluster analysis.
  - In **SPSS** the hierarchical cluster analysis procedure allows you to cluster by variables. The procedure uses the `proximities` command to generate the distance matrix.

#### Variables and clusters:

When running a cluster analysis on variables, you need to think about what formula you will use to generate your distance matrix.

- Common ways of calculating distances between variables (i.e., the items in your survey) include the `squared euclidean distance` or `one minus the correlation`.
  In both the cases, the distance between negative and positively worded items on the same dimension will appear distant. Thus, when you run a cluster analysis, such items will not cluster together.
- However, if you want such items to cluster together, you can choose a measure of distance between items that sees negatively correlated items as similar. A few ideas include:

  - Reverse the negatively worded items before entering them into the cluster analysis.
  - Use `1 minus absolute correlation` as the measure of distance

In general, cluster analysis is an algorithmic and atheoretical way of examining groupings in your variables. You have a lot of freedom in how you define distances and how you aggregate based on those distances. The important consideration is that you align your conceptual definition of distance with your operational algorithm for measuring distance.